# Connect device for debugging with Android?

Tags: android

I need to connect my device (Sony S) to eclipse for debugging. How can I do this?

I've got it plugged in, and set up for development with debugging mode turned on.

I have adb devices to see if its there and it isnt.

I am on OSX 10.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux, the solution is to do the following:

```
$ ./adb kill-server
$ sudo ./adb devices
```

So please try to open a terminal window and change to the directory where you have adb.
Try to execute the same commands I've written above and let me know if it works for you.